# subset a column in data frame based on another data frame/list

Tags: r, subset, apply

I have the following `table1` which is a data frame composed of 6 columns and 8083 rows. Below I am displaying the head of this `table1`:

```
|gene ID        |   prom_65|   prom_66|  amast_69|  amast_70|   p_value|
|:--------------|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|
|LdBPK_321470.1 |   24.7361|   25.2550|   31.2974|   45.4209| 0.2997430|
|LdBPK_251900.1 |  107.3580|  112.9870|   77.4182|   86.3211| 0.0367792|
|LdBPK_331430.1 |   72.0639|   86.1486|   68.5747|   77.8383| 0.2469355|
|LdBPK_100640.1 |   43.8766|   53.4004|   34.0255|   38.4038| 0.1299948|
|LdBPK_330360.1 | 2382.8700| 1871.9300| 2013.4200| 2482.0600| 0.8466225|
|LdBPK_090870.1 |   49.6488|   53.7134|   59.1175|   66.0931| 0.0843242|
```

I have another data frame, called `accessions40` which is a list of 510 gene IDs. It is a subset of the first column of `table1` i.e. all of its values (510) are contained in the first column of `table1` (8083). The head of `accessions40` is displayed below:

```
|V1             |
|:--------------|
|LdBPK_330360.1 |
|LdBPK_283000.1 |
|LdBPK_360210.1 |
|LdBPK_261550.1 |
|LdBPK_367320.1 |
|LdBPK_361420.1 |
```

What I want to do is the following: I want to produce a new `table2` which contains under the first column (gene ID) only the values present in `accessions40` and the corresponding values from the other five columns from `table1`. In other words, I want to subset the first column of my `table1` based on the values of `accessions40`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to get a logical vector and `subset` the rows of the 'table1' based on that.

```
subset(table1, gene_ID %in% accessions40$V1)
```

---

A better option would be `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(table1)[gene_ID %chin% accessions40$V1]
```

Or use `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
table1 %>%
      filter(gene_ID %in% accessions40$V1)
```

Comment: How to filter the values in gene_ID that are not in accession40$V1?

Comment: @RanonKahn Use the negate (`!` i.e. `setDT(table)[!gene_ID %chin% accessions40$V1]`

Comment: I was using the negate sign in the wrong place and running into error. Thanks!

Comment: Although it's late, happy to hear from you.  I have the same problem and I used this subset code, but it gave an empty output file that had just the name of the columns in the first (original) file, that called "table1" in this post. Could you please help me out to solve the issue?

Comment: @Mary please consider to post as a new question with a reproducible example

Answer (score 13):

There are many ways to do this. Finding the `gene_ID` in `table1` which are present in `V1` column of `accession40`

```
table1[table1$gene_ID %in% accessions40$V1, ]
```

---

Or you can also use `match`

```
table1[match(accessions40$V1, table1$gene_ID), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`semi_join`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter-joins.html) does not get used often, but works for this case:

```
dplyr::semi_join(table1, accessions40, by = c('gene_ID' = 'V1'))
```

The first data frame is subset by the second, only when there is a match. If `by` is not specified, then by default it will filter by all intersecting columns.

**Data**

```
table1 <- structure(list(gene_ID = c("LdBPK_321470.1", "LdBPK_251900.1", 
                                     "LdBPK_331430.1", "LdBPK_100640.1", "LdBPK_330360.1", "LdBPK_090870.1"
), prom_65 = c(24.7361, 107.358, 72.0639, 43.8766, 2382.87, 49.6488
), prom_66 = c(25.255, 112.987, 86.1486, 53.4004, 1871.93, 53.7134
), amast_69 = c(31.2974, 77.4182, 68.5747, 34.0255, 2013.42, 
                59.1175), amast_70 = c(45.4209, 86.3211, 77.8383, 38.4038, 2482.06, 
                                       66.0931), p_value = c(0.299743, 0.0367792, 0.2469355, 0.1299948, 
                                                             0.8466225, 0.0843242)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                         -6L))

accessions40 <- structure(list(V1 = c("LdBPK_330360.1", "LdBPK_283000.1", "LdBPK_360210.1", 
                                      "LdBPK_261550.1", "LdBPK_367320.1", "LdBPK_361420.1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                  -6L))
```