# subset dataframe based on rownames

Tags: r

I have two data frames (`bwenv` and `bwsp`). `bwsp` is a subset of `bwenv` and they have matching rownames (sample id). I would like to subset `bwenv` so that it only includes the rows that are also found in `bwsp`.

When the number of rows match, I have used:

> bw2015 <- cbind(bwenv, bwsp)

to create a new dataframe with the combined data.

My question is very similar to the question asked here: [R subset a column in data frame based on another data frame/list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850629/r-subset-a-column-in-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame-list), but the subsetting is done by a column of data in each dataframe (rather than row names like I want to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from @yeedle's solution, I modified it a little and found this worked for me:

```
library(dplyr)
bwenv2 <- bwenv %>% 
  rownames_to_column("row_names") %>%
  semi_join(rownames_to_column(bwsp, "row_names"), by = "row_names")
rownames(bwenv2) <- bwenv2$row_names 
bwenv2 <- bwenv2 %>% select(-row_names)

bw2015 <- cbind(bwenv2, bwsp)
str(bw2015)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

bw2015 <- bwenv %>% 
  add_rownames("row_names") %>%
  semi_join(add_rownames(bwsp, "row_names"), by = "row_names")
```

Comment: Thank you! After doing this, I can reassign the first column back into row names.

Comment: yes. `rownames(bw2015) <- bw2015$row_names` and then `bw2015 <-
 bw2015 %>% select(-row_names)`

Comment: Oh, I think I spoke too soon after your initial solution. I'm getting an error message that says: `Warning message:
Deprecated, use tibble::rownames_to_column() instead. `