# Subset Data based on separate Dataframe (R)

Tags: r, subset

I know that variants of this question have been asked before and I have tried solutions from ([Select rows from a data frame based on values in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612235/select-rows-from-a-data-frame-based-on-values-in-a-vector)) and ([subset a column in data frame based on another data frame/list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850629/subset-a-column-in-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame-list)) but I haven't been able to make these solutions work. The solutions keep returning a data frame with 0 observations.

My first data frame looks something like this:

```
> head(test3)
  long    lat     time   precip  GID_0   GID_1   HASC_1
168.75 -46.25 Jan_1979 5.534297   NZL  NZL.14_1  NZ.SO
171.25 -43.75 Jan_1979 4.191629   NZL  NZL.3_1   NZ.CA
146.25 -41.25 Jan_1979 3.139199   AUS  AUS.9_1   AU.TS
173.75 -41.25 Jan_1979 1.770889   NZL  NZL.8_1   NZ.MA
176.25 -38.75 Jan_1979 2.257812   NZL  NZL.17_1  NZ.WK
141.25 -36.25 Jan_1979 1.985313   AUS  AUS.10_1  AU.VI
```

I have a separate data frame that contains a single column with ID values that looks like this:

```
> head(africa_iso)
ISO
DZA
AGO
SHN
BEN
BWA
BFA
```

I'd like to filter the first dataframe so that only observations that match on GID_0 and ISO are remaining (conceptually, the first dataset includes observations for all countries, I'd like to filter this to a dataset with observations from African countries only). I currently have 725,517 observations in the first data frame and I expect to have approximately 200k observations after filtering.

These have been my attempts so far and every time I'm left with a new data frame that has 7 columns and no observations.

```
Afr <- subset(test3, GID_0 %in% africa_iso$ISO) #attempt 1

Afr <- setDT(test3)[GID_0 %in% africa_iso$ISO] #attempt 2

Afr <- test3[test3$GID_0 %in% africa_iso$ISO,] #attempt 3

Afr <- filter(test3$GID_0 %in% africa_iso$ISO  ) #attempt 4

Afr <- setDT(test3)[GID_0 %chin% africa_iso$ISO] #attempt 5

Afr <- test3[match(test3$GID_0, africa_iso$ISO),] #attempt 6

Afr <-test3[is.element(test3$GID_0, africa_iso$ISO),] #attempt 7
```

I'm sure this is a trivial problem for someone else, but I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

EDIT:

```
> str(test3)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  725517 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ long  : num  169 171 146 174 176 ...
 $ lat   : num  -46.2 -43.8 -41.2 -41.2 -38.8 ...
 $ time  : Factor w/ 477 levels "Jan_1979","Feb_1979",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1        
 $ precip: num  5.53 4.19 3.14 1.77 2.26 ...
 $ ISO   :'data.frame': 725517 obs. of  1 variable:
..$ : chr  "NZL" "NZL" "AUS" "NZL" ...
 $ ISOP  :'data.frame': 725517 obs. of  1 variable:
..$ : chr  "NZL.14_1" "NZL.3_1" "AUS.9_1" "NZL.8_1" ...
 $ HASC  :'data.frame': 725517 obs. of  1 variable:
..$ : chr  "NZ.SO" "NZ.CA" "AU.TS" "NZ.MA" ...
- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

And

```
> str(africa_iso)
'data.frame':   62 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ ISO: Factor w/ 57 levels "AGO","BDI","BEN",..: 14 1 43 3 5 4 2 8 12 6 ...
```

Comment: Please check the `str` of both datasets.  One issue might be that the column 'ISO' can be  a `factor` with some leadng/lagging spaces.  So exact match fails in that case.  Try with `trimws(africa_iso$ISO)` and similarly for `trimws(GID_0)`  (removes the leading/lagging spaces)

Comment: Thank you; I tried Afr ' <- test3[trimws(test3$GID_0) %in% trimws(africa_iso$ISO),] ' and am still getting a data frame with no observations.

Comment: Please put the output from `str` in the question, not in a comment. Much easier to read up there! And `trimws` does not indicate `factor` as @akrun suggested. The use of `str` or (better yet) `dput` gives a better indication of column classes.

Comment: It's also impossible to really test with this data since your examples have no overlap between `test3$ISO` and `africa_iso$ISO`.

Comment: sorry, I am new to R; I know there is overlap between the two (I can see it when I bring up the datasets side by side). I added the output from str to the original post.

Comment: In `str(test3)`, there isn't a variable called `GID_0`. The values you want to match appear to be in the variable `ISO`, which is actually a _data.frame_ with one variable of type `character`. If you fix your data frame, then you should solve that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several of your columns in `test3` are not proper `character`: they are embedded `data.frame`s, which is complicating your lookup. If you are not doing this intentionally, you can correct this with:

```
isdf <- sapply(test3, is.data.frame)
test3[isdf] <- lapply(test3[isdf], `[[`, 1)
subset(test3, GID_0 %in% africa_iso$ISO)
#     long    lat     time   precip GID_0    GID_1 HASC_1
# 1 168.75 -46.25 Jan_1979 5.534297   NZL NZL.14_1  NZ.SO
# 2 171.25 -43.75 Jan_1979 4.191629   NZL  NZL.3_1  NZ.CA
# 4 173.75 -41.25 Jan_1979 1.770889   NZL  NZL.8_1  NZ.MA
# 5 176.25 -38.75 Jan_1979 2.257812   NZL NZL.17_1  NZ.WK
```

I previously altered your `africa_iso` to include `NZL` so that there would be a match:

```
> dput(africa_iso)
structure(list(ISO = structure(c(5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("NZL", 
"BEN", "BFA", "BWA", "DZA", "SHN"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I should note that this works fine assuming all of your embedded frames are single-column. If anything is 2 or more, this solution will result in loss of data.