# filter a dataframe by a column of another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have a dataframe with coordinates and site id's for 117 sites and I want to filter it and make a new df which only contains the data of a select 50 sites, of which the ID's are in another df.
Below is my code, however I got this error `"longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"`

*Code:*

```
longlat_LH <- longlat %>% filter(site_id == LH_sites$site_id)
```

Comment: You may need `%in%` infix operator rather than `==` in the filter function.
Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850629/subset-a-column-in-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame-list

Comment: A left_join() could also do it

Comment: `semi_join` is useful for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Match` can be useful in your case

`longlat_LH <- longlat[match(LH_sites$site_id, longlat$site_id), ]`

And with `dplyr` just like @Imran suggested try

```
longlat %>%
   filter(site_id %in% LH_sites$site_id)`
```

Comment: @neil Langan, If we have answered your question correctly, its always a good practice to 
 *[vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)