# Ifelse subset - (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm doing exactly what is needed in [this](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850629/subset-a-column-in-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame-list) question except that I want to make a new column in the original dataframe with true or false values for the rows where the subset occurs.

```
ifelse(subset(reads_matrix, rownames(reads_matrix) %in% crass$Crass_hits)
                         ,reads_matrix$Crass <- c('TRUE'),
                         reads_matrix$Crass <- c('FALSE'))
```

evaluates to:

```
Error in ifelse(subset(reads_matrix, rownames(reads_matrix) %in% crass$Crass_hits), : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
```

I have also tried:

```
reads_matrix$Crass <- ifelse(subset(reads_matrix, rownames(reads_matrix) %in% crass$Crass_hits),'TRUE','FALSE')



if (subset(reads_matrix, rownames(reads_matrix) %in% crass$Crass_hits)){
    reads_matrix$Crass <- c('TRUE')
}
    reads_matrix$Crass <- c('FALSE')


for (row in rownames(reads_matrix)){
    if(subset(reads_matrix,row %in% crass$Crass_hits)){
        reads_matrix$Crass <- c('TRUE')
    }
       reads_matrix$Crass <- c('FALSE')
}


Warning message in if (subset(reads_matrix, row %in% crass$Crass_hits)) {:
“the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used”

Error in if (subset(reads_matrix, row %in% crass$Crass_hits)) {: argument is not interpretable as logical
Traceback:
```

Comment: Your first argument to `ifelse` is a data.frame which is a list object. For instance compare `ifelse(mtcars, 1, 0)` with `ifelse(mtcars == 4, 1, 0)`.

Comment: I got it now thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
crass_subset<-subset(reads_matrix, rownames(reads_matrix) %in% crass$Crass_hits)

reads_matrix$Crass <- ifelse(rownames(reads_matrix) %in% crass_subset, 1, 0)
```