# Subset dataframe based on exact matches between two dataframes in R

Tags: r

Subset a dataframe based on another dataframe. how to deal with overlap in character strings?

```
DF1
| EvalID  | Transect | size
|RO-94 | A | 2
|RO-93 | A | 2
|RO-92 | AB | 14
|RO-91 | B | 25
|RO-90 | BC | 1
|RO-89 | C | 3
|RO-88 | CD | 1
|RO-87 | CD | 50
|RO-86 | D | 70
```

---

```
DF2
| EvalID  | Transect | depth
|RO-93 | A | .1
|RO-92 | A | 1.1
|RO-90 | BC | 0.5
|RO-89 | C | 2.1
|RO-87 | CD | .01
```

So I am trying to subset df1 by matching both the evalID and transect columns from df2. by using the following code:

tempdf <- subset(df1, Transect %in% df2$Transect & EvaluationID %in% df2$EvaluationID)

(originally found here [subset a column in data frame based on another data frame/list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850629/subset-a-column-in-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame-list) )

However, when I run this code on my data the output contains entries with 'AB' transects when df2 only has entries with transect 'A'. I assume that since 'A' in part of the string 'AB', those are being included but I would like to only keep exact matches if possible. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It's not a string thing, it's the simultaneity of the matches. This is better framed as a join operation. With `dplyr` you can do `semi_join(df1, df2)`, or in base `merge(df1, df2[c("EvalID", "Transect")])`.

Comment: semi_join seems to have worked thank you!